# Typo in Morton Knots notes?

Tags: complex-numbers, knot-theory

apologies if I'm just missing something obvious. I'm reading the [H.R.Morton "Knots and Links" notes](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/%7Esu14/papers/KNOT2002.pdf) with no background, just for fun, and I'm in section 2, where two great circles have been defined (p.11):
$$ C_1 = \{ ((x_1, x_2, x_3),t) \in S^3 : x_1 = x_2 = 0 \} $$
and $$C_2 = \{( x_1, x_2, x_3), t) \in S^3 : x_3 = t = 0 \}. $$
Later, we switch from thinking of $(x_1, x_2, x_3, t) \in \mathbb{R}^4 $ to $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ with $z_1 = x_1 + i x_2$ and $z_2 = x_3 + i t$ (bottom of page). Then I see why $S^3$ is given by $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1$, but then they say $C_1$ is given by $z_2 = 0$ and $C_2$ is given by $z_1 = 0$. This continues throughout more discussion in examples, the idea that $C_2$ is associated with $z_1 = 0$. But I just thought that it should be reversed, $C_1$ given by $z_1 = 0$ because $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ in there, etc. Am I just going crazy?

Comment: To me it also seems like a mistake, $C_{1}$ should be associated with $z_{1}$ and similar for $C_{2}$.